# webpush, How to open window if no tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, service-worker, web-push

I've setup a web push system and it works fairly well.

The problem I have is that on Mac, if the user has Firefox open but without any page opened when he gets a notification the click is lost. 
I
t doesn't do anything at all.

here's the relevant part

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

  var jsonObj = event.data.json();
  var title = jsonObj.title;

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      'body': jsonObj.body,
      'icon': jsonObj.icon,
      'href': jsonObj.href,
      'tag': jsonObj.tag

    }));

    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
      event.notification.close();
      var href = jsonObj.href;
      var tag  = jsonObj.tag;

      if (clients.openWindow) {
        clients.openWindow(href);
      }


      /*
      // This looks to see if the current is already open and
      // focuses if it is
      event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({
          type: "window"
        })
        .then(function(clientList) {
          for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
            var client = clientList[i];
            if (client.url == href && 'focus' in client)
              return client.focus();
          }
          if (clients.openWindow) {
            return clients.openWindow(href);
          }
        })
      );
    */
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to:

1. Define the `notificationclick` event handler outside the `push` event handler, in the global scope. You can pass the `jsonObj` in the `data` parameter of `showNotification`, so you'll have access to it in the `event` object in the `notificationclick` handler. You can see an example here: https://github.com/mozilla/wp-web-push/blob/master/wp-web-push/lib/js/sw.php.
2. [openWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow) returns a Promise, you should call event.waitUntil with the promise returned by openWindow.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make some tests and post the results.

Comment: It seems to be working as intended, but it is not able to open a window if the browser doesn't have any :(

Comment: There's currently a bug in Firefox which prevents this from working when there are no windows opened (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226434).